# How to display a bitmap in SharpDX?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, .net-4.5, sharpdx

I am trying to make a very simple game for learning purposes, but i am struggling with SharpDX.
Basically what i'm trying to achieve is: Take several bitmap images and display them in a window on certain x y coordinates. After that, i will clear the window a display those images again, but on different x y coordinates (a very basic game loop basically, which means the images will be re-displayed many times per second).

I have this code:

```
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Toolkit;

internal sealed class MyGame : Game
{
    private readonly GraphicsDeviceManager _graphicsDeviceManager;

    public MyGame()
    {
        _graphicsDeviceManager = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
-------
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        using (var game = new MyGame())
            game.Run();
    }
}
```

When compiled, it simply opens a window with a blue background.

Then, I have two images:

```
var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:/img/pic1.png")); 
var img1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:/img/pic2.png"));
```

And this is where the problem lies, i am unable to figure out, how to take these two images and actually display them in the window.  `img` should be displayed at x10 y50 coordinates (or in other words, 10 pixels  from the left side of the window, and 50 pixels from the top) and `img1` at x200 y150 coordinates.

I'm sure the solution is something easy, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside **MyGame**.

Firstly, in `LoadContent` method load the texture:

```
private Texture2D myTexture;

protected override void LoadContent()        
{
    this.myTexture = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Path to img");
}
```

then in `Draw`;

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    var sprite = new SpriteBatch(this.GraphicsDevice);
    sprite.Begin();

    sprite.Draw(this.myTexture,
                    new Rectangle(10, 50, // position: x and y coordiantes in pixels
                                   /* width and height below
                                            - do not remeber order: */ 
                                  25,  25),
                    Color.White);

    sprite.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

This is the basic way to draw anything with `SharpDX`.